# Magento model loading but it returns empty data set

Tags: magento, customization, magento-1.9

I've created custom module.I'm trying to get data from my table.

[image]

```
Mage::getModel('suits/suits');
```

But unfortunately it returns empty dataset.Getting data for collections.

**Config.xml:**

```
  <models>
        <suits>
            <class>Bespoke_Suits_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>suits_resource</resourceModel>
        </suits>
        <suits_resource>
            <class>Bespoke_Suits_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <suits>
                    <table>suits</table>
                </suits>
            </entities>
        </suits_resource>
    </models>
```

**Model/Suits.php**

```
<?php

class Bespoke_Suits_Model_Suits extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{

public function _construct(){
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('suits/suits');
}

public function load($id, $field=null){
    $resource =  $this->_getResource();
    if (!$resource) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException('Resource instance is not available');
    }
    return parent::load($bespoke_id, $field);
}   

public function test(){
    echo "test!!";
}
}
```

**Module/Resource/Suits.php**

```
<?php

class Bespoke_Suits_Model_Resource_Suits extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract{

public function _construct(){
    //parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('suits/suits','suits_id');
}
}
```

Found similar questions here,but still not getting data.

Comment: you mean the load method is not retutning anything ? or you are trying to `getCollection()`

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab i'm trying to get data from my table?

Comment: you either load a specific row `Mage::getModel('suits/suits')->load(primary_key_here)` or you do a `select * from .... `  with  `Mage::getModel('suits/suits')->getCollection();`

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab i tried same way.But no luck.Can you check my code,is there anything wrong in that or missed anything

Comment: Can you please review this http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/ and also http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-model-database-tutorial-54 , I can not spot what you are missing since I dont know what you exactly have done and what is not there.

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab i referred [kamleshkamble.blogspot.in/2013/02/custom-module-in-magento-with-custom.html] post.Ok i'll look in to that.If i get solution i'll post it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96815/discussion-between-rabee-abdelwahab-and-nagendra).

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab Problem Solved.Removed `load()` function from `Model/Suits.php`.